# Error sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, xml, spring, security, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.1.6; spring security 4.0.1; spring oauth2-2.0.7 jar files.
When I am compiling the code I am getting this error :

```
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:schooldays' did not find a matching property.
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.13.0-55-generic
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/shamim/uworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/shamim/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Ddeploy.env=dev
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.rapidinstinct.ucap.deploy.environment=dev
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/shamim/uworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/shamim/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/shamim/uworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/shamim/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/endorsed
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 675 ms
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/shamim/uworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/schooldays/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 47 more

Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/schooldays] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 28, 2015 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3795 ms
```

My web.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Dispatcher Servlet (Front Controller / Servlet Context) only presentation 
        layer is defined here. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the dispatcher-servlet.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="  info.xyz.controller,
                                            info.xyz.cdo,
                                            info.xyz.service,
                                            info.xyz.serviceImpl,
                                            info.xyz.mapper
                                            " />

    <!-- Database Connection information XML file import -->
    <import resource="classpath:/dbConnection/mongo-beans.xml" />

</beans>
```

And the rest-dispatcher-servlet.xml file is :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
    <http 
        pattern="/oauth/token" 
        create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
            <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- Protected resources -->
    <http 
        pattern="/main/**"
        create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/main/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Token Store -->
    <!-- <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" /> -->

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server 
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server 
        id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="dstest" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices" />


    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client 
            client-id="my-trusted-client"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
            authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" 
            redirect-uri="/web"
            scope="read,write,trust" 
            access-token-validity="300"
            refresh-token-validity="600" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>
    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

In rest-dispatcher-servlet.xml add to a tag `http` an attribute `use-expressions="true"` in a section

```
 <http 
        pattern="/main/**"
        create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/main/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

From [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html):

> To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to
>   set the use-expressions attribute in the  element to true.
>   Spring Security will then expect the access attributes of the
>    elements to contain Spring EL expressions. The
>   expressions should evaluate to a boolean, defining whether access
>   should be allowed or not.

And in this section change

```
<intercept-url pattern="/main/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

where

> hasRole([role])   - returns true if the current principal has the
>   specified role.

Comment: Hey Alex, Sorry to say but issue remains the same with same exception  :  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1];

Comment: Why do you write `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"` for each tag? It's not nesessary.